# When running my basic c# console app, my console opens blank and I don't know why

Tags: c#, console

I'm making a small game to assist me in learning c#. All I have done so far is added some variables like fullName, firstName, and lastName so I can reference them later on. That worked fine. But when I cam to the issue of adding a name prefix like Mr. or Ms. (I called them "titles" in the code) the console just opens up blank. Here's my code...

```
using System;

namespace My_Fist_Console_Game
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userValue = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Airport Sim: Console Edition (literally)");
            Console.Write("Type your first name here: ");
            string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Type your last name here: ");
            string lastName = Console.ReadLine();

            string title;

            Console.Write("are you male or female?");
            if ((userValue == "male") || (userValue == "Male"))
            {
                title = "Mr. ";
            }
            else if ((userValue == "female") || (userValue == "Female"))
            {
                title = "Ms. ";
            }

            string fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;

            Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Flight Attendant: ");
            Console.WriteLine("    Hello " + title + " " + lastName);





            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first statement in your program is `Console.ReadLine` which waits for the user to input something. Since you never told it to print to the console *before* that the console opens and appears blank.

If you input something and hit "Enter" then the code could continue executing and you would see output.

Comment: Thanks! Now that I removed the "userValue = Console.ReadLine();", what would I do so that the userValue in the if statements would still recognize male, Male, female, etc?

Comment: See Willy's answer for a good example of how to modify it so that still works

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

namespace My_Fist_Console_Game
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Airport Sim: Console Edition (literally)");
            Console.Write("Type your first name here: ");
            string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Type your last name here: ");
            string lastName = Console.ReadLine();

            string title;
            while (title != "Mr. " && title != "Ms. ")


            {
                Console.Write("are you male or female? Input male, if you are male       or imput female if you are female");

                string userValue = Console.ReadLine();
                if ((userValue == "male") || (userValue == "Male"))
                {
                    title = "Mr. ";
                }
                else if ((userValue == "female") || (userValue == "Female"))
                {
                    title = "Ms. ";
                }
            }
            string fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;

            Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Flight Attendant: ");
            Console.WriteLine("    Hello " + title + " " + lastName);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your uservalue variable above your condition:

```
string userValue = Console.ReadLine(); 
        if ((userValue == "male") || (userValue == "Male"))
        {
            title = "Mr. ";
        }
```

Then try to edit this part:

```
string fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;

        Console.ReadLine(); //Remove this and put it after Console.WriteLine

        Console.Clear(); //Remove this and put it after Console.WriteLine

        Console.WriteLine("Flight Attendant: ");
        Console.WriteLine("    Hello " + " " + lastName);
```

What you are doing is you are putting Console.ReadLine() which will expect any input from the user first before anything happens on your program.